# WordPress database error MySQL server has gone away for query SELECT

Tags: php, wordpress

Using wordpress multisite, when trying to cutomize theme got this error log :

`WordPress database error MySQL server has gone away for query SELECT option_value FROM tblog_c4c.wp_6010_options WHERE option_name = 'post_count' LIMIT 1 made by do_action('customize_controls_enqueue_scripts'), call_user_func_array, WP_Customize_Widgets->enqueue_scripts, WP_Customize_Widgets->get_available_widgets, WP_Customize_Widgets->get_widget_control, call_user_func_array, wp_widget_control, call_user_func_array, WP_Widget->form_callback, NLposts_Widget->form, get_blog_details, get_option, m_wpdb->query`

and browser display `504 Gateway Time-out`

Already increased the time limits by:

`set_time_limit(0);`

`ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', '0');`

`ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');`

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can Fix it by setting max_allowed_packet = 16M in my.cnf and restarting mysql

Comment: I applied this by:
`$db = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname' );`
`// to get the max_allowed_packet`
`$maxp = $db->query( 'SELECT @@global.max_allowed_packet' )->fetch_array();`
`echo $maxp[ 0 ];`
`// to set the max_allowed_packet to 500MB`
`$db->query( 'SET @@global.max_allowed_packet = ' . 500 * 1024 * 1024 );`
It changed my packet_max but not solved my problem.